# C# Webserver only send HTML code to client

Tags: c#, http, server

```
public void Initialise()
    {
        listener = new StreamSocketListener();

        // listen on port 80, this is the standard HTTP port (use a different port if you have a service already running on 80)
        listener.BindServiceNameAsync("80").AsTask();
        listener.ConnectionReceived += async (sender, args) =>
        {
        // call the handle request function when a request comes in
        HandleRequest(sender, args);
        };


    public async void HandleRequest(StreamSocketListener sender, StreamSocketListenerConnectionReceivedEventArgs args)
    {
        StringBuilder request = new StringBuilder();

        // Handle a incoming request
        // First read the request
        using (IInputStream input = args.Socket.InputStream)
        {
            byte[] data = new byte[BufferSize];
            IBuffer buffer = data.AsBuffer();
            uint dataRead = BufferSize;
            while (dataRead == BufferSize)
            {
                await input.ReadAsync(buffer, BufferSize, InputStreamOptions.Partial);
                request.Append(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data, 0, data.Length));
                dataRead = buffer.Length;
            }
        }

        // Send a response back
        using (IOutputStream output = args.Socket.OutputStream)
        {
            using (Stream response = output.AsStreamForWrite())
            {
                // For now we are just going to reply to anything with Hello World!

                //byte[] bodyArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("<html><body>Hello, World!</body></html>");
                string page = "";
                var folder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
                var file = await folder.GetFileAsync("index.html");
                var readFile = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadLinesAsync(file);
                foreach(var line in readFile)
                {
                    page += line;
                }
                byte[] bodyArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(page);

                var bodyStream = new MemoryStream(bodyArray);
                // This is a standard HTTP header so the client browser knows the bytes returned are a valid http response
                var header = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n" +
                            $"Content-Length: {bodyStream.Length}\r\n" +
                                "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";

                byte[] headerArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(header);

                // send the header with the body included to the client
                await response.WriteAsync(headerArray, 0, headerArray.Length);
                await bodyStream.CopyToAsync(response);
                await response.FlushAsync();
            }
        }

    }

        private StreamSocketListener listener; // the socket listner to listen for TCP requests
                                               // Note: this has to stay in scope!

        private const uint BufferSize = 8192; // this is the max size of the buffer in bytes 
    }
}
```

Hello,

i implemented in my c# program a http server to send a webinterface to the client. This webinterface (index.html) includes some css styles and js methods. My Problem is that the client browser only shows the html code without for example the styles. How is it possible to send the "whole" folder with all webinterface files to the client?

Comment: the styles an js files are referenced.

Comment: the browser will make separate requests using the same connection for the css and js.  Your code ends after handling the first request.

Comment: when i enter the ip of the server in my client browser, the client asks for index.html, right? In the index.html are referenced css and javascript. The reference starts a new request automatically? how can i solve my problem? Must i parse the request an send aall files seperate?

Comment: @Ollifred yes, you must parse and send all files individually, which means your code needs a way to identify which file is being requested.  As a side note, why are you trying to do it this way instead of using one of the other more common, tested server implementations already bundled with the .net framework?

Comment: Assuming you have a good reason for your approach, the only other reasonable way to get CSS to be read from your server when the HTML is loaded is to embed the stylesheets directly into the HTML page. The same goes for external javascript references.

Comment: ok, thanks for your help so far. it is not necessary to use this method. what are the alternatives to implement a webserver in a c# project?